# How to remove the word using array index in perl?

Tags: perl

How to remove the certain words using array index for the following input using Perl?

```
file.txt
BOCK:top:blk1
BOCK:block2:blk2
BOCK:test:blk3
```

After join:

```
/BOCK/top/blk1
/BOCK/block2/blk2
/BOCK/test/blk3
```

Expected output:

```
/BOCK/blk1
/BOCK/blk2
/BOCK/blk3
```

Code which I had tried:

```
use warnings;
use strict;
my @words;
open(my $infile,'<','file.txt') or die $!;
while(<$infile>)
{
    push(@words,split /\:/);
}
my $word=join("/",@words);
print $word;
close ($infile);
foreach my $word(@words)
{
    if($word=~ /(\w+\/\w+\/\w+)/)
    {
        print $word;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand what you want to do. The `$3` in the last `if` is always `undef` because you don't have three capture groups and also because each `$word` has no slash `/` in it. It can't because it got `split` on slash before. You should also get a warning that you are redefining a variable in a smaller scope. Why you want to use an array index? You are doing overly complicated stuff to get to your output.

Comment: i prefer array index so that i can easily remove the mid word from the array and process for the expected output@simbabque

Comment: simbabque is correct. This is overly complicated and can be simplified to drop out the middle word.

Comment: How can i simplify it.I had took it in array and also i need to convert colon to slashes.Can you please help me to simplify it@Gerry

Comment: I was busy then simbabque posted answer :)

Comment: you are building a long list of words in you `while` loop, not a list of concatenations of 3 words

Comment: Quick, Dirty, Onetime,Oneliner: `perl -pE 's{\A([^:]+).*:([^:]*)\z}{/$1/$2}'  < input > output`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way to get rid of the middle element is to use [`splice`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/splice.html).

```
while ( my $line = <DATA> ) {
    my @words;
    push( @words, split( /:/, $line ) );    # colon has no special meaning
    splice( @words, 1, 1 );
    print '/', join( '/', @words );
}

__DATA__
BOCK:top:blk1
BOCK:block2:blk2
BOCK:test:blk3
```

I assumed that you want to do that for every line. The code that you had did something else. Because your `@words` is declared outside of the `while` loop it gets bigger withe every iteration, and every third element contains a newline `\n` character because you never `chomp`. Then you build create one long `$word` that has all the words from all lines joined with a slash `/`. Afterwards you try to match that for three words joined with slashes, which works. But you only have one capture group, so your `$3` is never defined.

Comment: Or `print join '/', @words[0,-1]`

Comment: @zdim yes, obviously. But that's not removing. ;)

Comment: Ah, yes, they explicitly ask to "_remove_". Was just a comment, not critique of any kind :)

Comment: I know @zdim. It's way more concise though and I'd prefer yours too.

Comment: add the wanted leading `/` to print

Comment: Great i had cleared with the mistake what i had done@simbabque

Answer (score 2):

The code can be simplified and cleaned up, even to the point of

```
my @paths = map { '/' . join '/', (split ':')[0,-1] } <$infile>;

print "$_\n" for @paths;
```

The [map](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/map.html) imposes the *list context* on the filehandle read, which thus returns a list of all lines from the file. The code in `map`'s block is applied to each element: it [split](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html)s the line and takes the first and last element of that list, [join](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/join.html)s them, and then prepends the leading `/`. Inside the block the line is in the [`variable $_`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#General-Variables), what `split` uses as default. The resulting list is returned and assigned to `@path`.

A number of errors in the posted code have been explained clearly in [simbabque's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42244956/4653379).

Thanks to [jm666](https://stackoverflow.com/users/632407/jm666) in a comment for catching the requirement for the  leading `/`.

---

The above can also be used for a one-liner

```
perl -F: -lane'print "/" . join "/", @F[0,-1]' < file.txt  > out.txt
```

The `-a` turns on autosplit mode (with `-n` or `-p`), whereby each line is split and available in `@F`. The `-F` switch allows to specify the pattern to split on, here `:`, instead of the default space.

See [switches in perlrun](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches).